What is the easiest way to ask for Network Permissions?
I have a Compose Multiplatform app and I require the application to communicate with the server. Hence I have the Ktor-client stuff inside the shared/ module and the Ktor Server on server/ module.
I hosted the server on my local network and installed the application on my module. However, the logcat has the message:

I found out that this is because I do not have any network permissions on my Android app for my android phone. Coming from the native Android development side, I thought I could add this to the Manifest file (at composeApp/src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application>...</application>
</manifest>

In a native android version, this would work. However, the app wouldn't install on my android phone with the uses-permission line.

How do I ask for Network permissions in my Compose Multiplatform application?


You don't want network permissions, you want cleartext permissions.  Those are different.  Network allows you to make a request to a server.  You have that above.  Cleartext allows you to make non-HTTPS requests (HTTP requests without encryption). The error you're showing is about not having cleartext permissions. That requires you to request cleartext by adding  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application tag in your manifest.  Please note that doing so may make your app rejected from the play store for security reasons.

This code is used for my university group project, so I don't mind if it is not HTTPS yet. Thanks for your answer. Do you know if this would work on iOS? If not, what steps I should take so that the iOS platform can make this network call as well?
